# Type erasure for binary operations

Tags: c++, type-erasure

It is possible to write a wrapper that takes any type that supports a certain operation, e.g.

```
#include <iostream>

class Houdini
{
  struct I_Houdini_Impl
  {
    virtual void foo_impl(int x) const = 0;

    virtual ~I_Houdini_Impl() { }
  };

  template <typename T>
  struct Houdini_Impl : I_Houdini_Impl
  {
    Houdini_Impl(T const & t) : m_t(t) { }

    void foo_impl(int x) const { m_t.foo(x); }

    T m_t;
  };
public:
  template <typename T>
  Houdini(T const & t) : m_impl(new Houdini_Impl<T>(t)) { }

  void foo(int x) const { m_impl->foo_impl(x); }
protected:
private:

  std::unique_ptr<I_Houdini_Impl> m_impl;
};

class A
{
public:
  void foo(int x) const { std::cout << "A::foo(" << x << ")" << std::endl; }
};

class B
{
public:
  template <typename T>
  char foo(T const & t) const { std::cout << "B::foo(" << t << ")" << std::endl; return 'B';}
};

void houdini()
{
  A a;
  B b;
  Houdini ha(a);
  Houdini hb(b);

  ha.foo(7);
  hb.foo(8);
}
```

I can wrap anything in the Houdini-class that supports a const-method foo that can be called wih an int, regardless if it is an ordinary member function (as in class A) or a function template (as in class B) (and lets disregard for now that Houdini should exhibit value sematics). So far so good, but what I would like to do is to write a wrapper that supports binary operations, e.g. to write a wrapper that accepts any type and you can, say, add any two wrappers as long as the wrapped objects can be added and returns the wrapped return object from the addition:

```
class A { };
class B { };
class C { };

C operator+(A, B) { return C(); }

class Randi
{
public:
  template <typename T> Randi(T ) { }

/* magic stuff goes here */
};

void randi()
{
  A a;
  B b;

  Randi ra(a);
  Randi rb(b);

  Randi rc = ra + rb;
  // rc is a Randi-object that wraps an object of type C
}
```

If I know in advance what types I am going to store I can do it by writing visitors but that is exactly what I do *not* want to do. I would need to unwrap both objects, try to call operator+ on the two unwrapped objects and wrap the result again but I cannot figure out how to do that.

Comment: I would say that with templates and magic this can be solved, but I'm not smart enough to know how.

Comment: I think you might be out of luck, given your current description.  Determining which possible overloads of `operator+` to use would require compile time knowledge of the types involved, but you've specifically erased that type information.  You might be able to do it for cases where both operands have to be the same type.

Answer (score 0):

Consider following

```
class Number
{
virtual Number* sum(Number* other) = 0;
};

class Int
     : public Number
{
    virtual Number* sum(Number* other)
    {
        // hard to implement since we doesn't know the type of other
    }
};


class Double
     : public Number

{
    virtual Number* sum(Number* other)
    {
        // hard to implement since we doesn't know the type of other
    }
};
```

We can do dynamic_casts in sum implementation to handle each case separately or we can use double dispatching.

```
class Double;
class Int;

class Number
{
public:
    virtual Number* sum(Number* other) = 0;
protected
    virtual Number* sum(Int* other) = 0; 
    virtual Number* sum(Double* other) = 0; 
};

class Int
     : public Number
{
    virtual Number* sum(Number* other)
    {
        return other->sum(this);
    }

    virtual Number* sum(Int* other)
    {
        // implement int + int
    }

    virtual Number* sum(Double* other)
    {
        // implement int + double
    }
};


class Double
     : public Number

{
    virtual Number* sum(Number* other)
    {
        return other->sum(this);
    }


    virtual Number* sum(Int* other)
    {
        // implement double + int
    }

    virtual Number* sum(Double* other)
    {
        // implement double + double
    }
};
```

In bot cases implementations should be aware about all derived classes. This means that analog of Houdini_Impl for Randi class should know about all other types that may be passed to Randi's constructor which is impossible.